# Action não está recebendo o valor do parâmetro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, imagem

No código abaixo estou tentando passar um parâmetro para uma Action. A action está sendo chamada e o valor do parâmetro também está sendo atribuído a Url. Porém a Action recebe Null, e não o valor do parâmetro.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "Terapeutas", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "form1", @name = "form1" }))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                foreach (var item in Model.Terapeutas)
                {
                    <img src="/Terapeutas/ShowFoto/@item.ID_TERAPEUTA" class="img-circle" alt="Foto Terapeuta" width="120" height="120" />
                }
            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você está chamando a `Action`, poderia adicionar o código?

Comment: <img src="/Terapeutas/ShowFoto/@item.ID_TERAPEUTA" class="img-circle" alt="Foto Terapeuta" width="120" height="120" />

Comment: Através da URL @Randrade

Comment: Você alterou seu routeConfig? Se não, tente essa rota aqui: `/Terapeutas/ShowFoto?id=@item.ID_TERAPEUTA`

Comment: Você é o cara @Randrade .. Funcionou blz..Valew

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta explicando melhor o funcionamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é que você não possui a configuração de rotas em seu arquivo `RouteConfig.cs`, por isso você não pode passar a **URL** desta forma. Para resolver o seu problema, você pode passar o parâmetro por [querystring](/questions/tagged/querystring) ou configurar sua rota.

Com **queryString** basta alterar seu `src` para isso:

```
<img src="/Terapeutas/ShowFoto?id=@item.ID_TERAPEUTA" class="img-circle" alt="Foto Terapeuta" width="120" height="120" />
```

Note que agora sua url irá ficar assim: **www.domain.com/terapeutas/showfoto?id=2**.

Para configurar sua rota e continuar usando da forma que está, basta adicionar isso em seu arquivo `RouteConfig.cs`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Fotos",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Terapeutas", action = "ShowFoto", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Desta forma você conseguirá acessar utiizando a forma que está.